# Logstash dynamic create field from configuration

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I tried to create dynamic the path from one filter but i get the error, when i try to start logstash.
The field service is send from logstash and i can see it on kibana.

Is not environment variable that i want. I want a field from logstash, when beat send to logstash.

Example:

Beat send data with: field: service , data: apache

logstash:

```
filter {
  data_dictionary_path => '/var/log/apache/data.log'
}
```

Any ideas ? :)

**Config file:**

```
filter {
  data_dictionary_path => '/var/log/${service}/data.log'
}
```

**Error msg:**

```
:message=>"No such file or directory - /var/log/${service}/data.log", :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyFile.java:366:in `initialize'",
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.bashrc` file, set the environment variable as below

```sh
export SERVICE=/var/log/continuining_path
```

In config file

```
filter {
   data_dictionary_path => "${SERVICE}/data.log"
}
```

Comment: Is not environment variable that i want to add here is field from beat that i send. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the grok filter?

```
grok {
match => { "data_dictionary_path" => "/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:service}/%{GREEDYDATA}" }
      }
```

Comment: I try with grok to create new field before add it on the other variable but is get the same error.